# What will be the SPF entry in DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, spam, spf, email

We are using magento on our server. Magento sent transactional emails directly from our server using php mail function, along with this we are using third party webmail service. Means our mx entry pointing to other server.

In this case what will be the valid SPF entry that also include SPF entries from webmail server as well  and is their any other dns entry we need to add?

Suppose our IP is `123.45.67.89`, MX server points to: `mail1.mailserver.com`,

New suggested SPF entry will

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:123.45.67.89 include:_spf.mailserver.com ?all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start with...

```
"v=spf1 ip4:aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd include:mail1.mailserver.com ?all"
```

Assuming your IP is `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` and your MX record points to `mail1.mailserver.com`, the above SPF / TXT record should work for your requirement.

Once the SPF record works correctly, you may consider switching the above record to the following...

```
"v=spf1 ip4:aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd include:mail1.mailserver.com -all"
```

The symbol before the `all` means the following... (ref: http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)

```
"+" Pass
"-" Fail
"~" SoftFail
"?" Neutral
```

You may also generate the SPF record using the online SPF generator from Microsoft at http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/ .

> is their any other dns entry we need to add?

Yes, you need to add the above as a 'TXT' record. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework .

Comment: Thanks Pothi. whats is difference between `include:_spf.mailserver.com` and  `include:mail1.mailserver.com`?

Comment: Just enter whatever the name of the mail server after `include:`. `mail1.mailserver.com` was the example I used. `_spf.mailserver.com` was the example you used. No other difference.